# Why does getProgramAccounts from the JSON RPC return empty result?

Tags: jsonrpc-api

Why does getProgramAccounts from the JSON RPC return empty result?

When I call getProgramAccounts from the RPC docs [here](https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#getprogramaccounts):

the result returned is this:
`{'jsonrpc': '2.0', 'result': [], 'id': 1}`

code used to call is exactly the same as the example request in the API:

```
{"jsonrpc": "2.0",
"id": 1,
"method": "getProgramAccounts",
"params": [
  "4Nd1mBQtrMJVYVfKf2PJy9NZUZdTAsp7D4xWLs4gDB4T",
  {
    "filters": [
      {
        "dataSize": 17
      },
      {
        "memcmp": {
          "offset": 4,
          "bytes": "3Mc6vR"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]}
```

Answer (score 2):

The pubkey used in the example "4Nd1mBQtrMJVYVfKf2PJy9NZUZdTAsp7D4xWLs4gDB4T" is not a valid program account. Please try with another program account pubkey.

Also note that memcmp is performed on bytes provided in the filter. If the bytes you provide as input is doesn't match, then the result can be empty.

Comment: hi - is there an example of an address that would work?